# How to send exported frame from wireshark directly in C(Both windows and linux are fine)?

Tags: network-protocols, wireshark

As the frame already includes all overhead of various layers,it can't be sent from the application layer again,instead,should be sent directly from the link-layer.Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pcap file created by Wireshark, you should be able to use [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/) to manipulate and replay it.

Comment: The exported frame can be in udp and any other network protocol,but `tcpreplay`,as its name implies,can only replay tcp frames..

Comment: I don't think that's true.  `tcpreplay`'s documentation suggests at least the ability to replay TCP, UDP, and ICMP packets, which would suggest that it extends to layer 3 or 4 packets in general.

Comment: it says it can replay libpcap format ,is that the same as the exported packet bytes of wireshark?

Comment: What type of file do you have?  In Wireshark, there is an Export option, but you would want to use the Save option.  The first file type it suggests is the libpcap (.pcap) format.